# Model class implementations for a generic solution

Tags: android, gson

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Paging

I have a generic solution in my classes using TmdbItem interface, such as :

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : TmdbItem> : BaseNavTypeFragment() {
    
   protected abstract val viewModel: BaseViewModel<T>

   protected lateinit var tmdbAdapter: TmdbAdapter<T>
}
```

TmdbItem interface and the class implementations are as follow :

```
interface TmdbItem : Parcelable {
    val id : Int
    val overview: String
    val releaseDate: String?
    val posterPath: String?
    val backdropPath: String?
    val name: String
    val voteAverage: Double
}

@Parcelize
data class Movie(
        override val id: Int,
        override val overview: String,
        @SerializedName("release_date")
        override val releaseDate: String?,
        @SerializedName("poster_path")
        override val posterPath: String?,
        @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
        override val backdropPath: String?,
        @SerializedName("title")
        override val name: String,
        @SerializedName("vote_average")
        override val voteAverage: Double) : TmdbItem

@Parcelize
data class TVShow(
        override val id: Int,
        override val overview: String,
        @SerializedName("first_air_date")
        override val releaseDate: String?,
        @SerializedName("poster_path")
        override val posterPath: String?,
        @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
        override val backdropPath: String?,
        override val name: String,
        @SerializedName("vote_average")
        override val voteAverage: Double) : TmdbItem
```

As you see I have to use `@SerializedName` in both classes even if the value is the same such as `poster_path` and `backdrop_path`. Is there anyway that I could write them in one place such as a base class instead of both class implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably not easily possible with Gson. The closest you could get to avoid duplicating the name is to define the property names somewhere as `const val` and then refer to them in `@SerializedName`, e.g. `@SerializedName(POSTER_PATH_NAME)`.

Another solution which is however quite complicated and error-prone would be:
Place `@SerializedName` on the getter functions of the interface, e.g. `@get:SerializedName("...")`. This is possible because `@SerializedName` supports `METHOD` as target, but Gson only considers it on fields by default. Then write a custom [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) which does the following:

1. Check if the field has a `@SerializedName` annotation, in that case return its value
2. Otherwise, obtain the Kotlin property (if any) for the Java field and obtain its getter method:

   ```kotlin
   field.kotlinProperty?.javaGetter
   ```
3. Check if the getter has a `@SerializedName`, in that case return its value
4. Otherwise, go through the superclasses and then superinterfaces to check if any of them declare the getter (which is overridden) and have a `@SerializedName`

This is how it might work in theory; I have not tried to fully implement this yet. And as you can see the logic would be quite complex, so I am not sure if that would really be worth it. Also keep in mind that Gson directly reads field values and does not call getters during serialization. Therefore using `@SerializedName` on getters (especially if they have a custom implementation) might cause confusion.

Otherwise you might have to look for external Gson extensions which support getter methods, or other JSON libraries.